# jQuery nested click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have the following markup:

```
<div data-href="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx.php/Mediterranean-Youth-Hostel/Barcelona/6053" data-id="6053" class="property-wrapper row">
    <div class="columns large-4 medium-4">v
        <img class="recent-viewed-img" src="http://ucd.xxxxxxxxx.com/propertyimages/6/6053/107.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-8 medium-8">
         <div class="info">
             <span class="city">Barcelona</span>
             <span class="close right">x</span>
         </div>
         <span class="hostel-title">Mediterranean Youth Hostel</span>
         <div class="rating">
             <span class="number">9.1</span>
             <span class="text">Fabulous</span>
         </div>
         <div class="bottom-info">
             <span class="price-from">From €9.90</span>
             <div class="icon_freewifi right">
                 <i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>Free WiFi
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and 2 js function with 2 different click events as follow:

this one allows you to click the all row and take you to anoter page:

```
$('.property-wrapper .columns').on('click', function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).parent().data('href');
});
```

this one simply closes and removes the row you just clicked on:

```
  $('body').on('click', '.close.right', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(200, function(){
      CRO_106_removePropertyFromCookie($(this));
      CRO_106_hideOverlayIfNoPropertiesLeft();
    });
  });
```

the problem is that when on `.close.right` it also goes to the other page.

The 2 click events are conflicting.

I can edit the markup, I have tried to have an "a" wrapper around but that didnt work either..

Comment: check the `event.target` in the click handler bound to `.columns`, if it's `.close.right`, prevent the redirect from occurring. You can't use `event.stopPropagation()` here because the second handler is bound to the `body`, so by the time you stop propagation, the click handler which does the redirect has already fired

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `event.target` inside of the `click` handler bound to `.property-wrapper .columns`, and if it's `.close.right`, you can prevent the redirect from occurring:

```
$( '.property-wrapper .columns' ).on( 'click', function( evt ) {
    if ( $( evt.target ).is( '.close.right' ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    window.location.href = $( this ).parent().data( 'href' );
} );
```

You can't use `event.stopPropagation()` in the handler bound to the `body` because the above click handler would have already fired, and the redirect already occurred.

[Here's a fiddle which demonstrates this](https://jsfiddle.net/j032b40m/) and [here's a fiddle with the proposed solution](https://jsfiddle.net/j032b40m/1/)